# local variable referenced before assignment User Registration Form

Tags: python, django, forms, variables

Goal: I'm trying to create a super simple user registration form.

I'm getting an error of: `local variable 'NewUserRegistrationForm' referenced before assignment`

I have a form in **forms.py**:

```
class NewUserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(required=True,max_length=30,validators=[RegexValidator('^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,30}$','e.g. must be 30 characters or less','Invalid Entry')])
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, max_length=75)
    password = forms.PasswordInput()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1","password2")

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(NewUserRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
    user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
    user.password = self.cleaned_data["password1"]
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user

form = NewUserRegistrationForm()
```

**views.py**

```
def Registration(request):
    NewUserRegistrationForm = NewUserRegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if NewUserRegistrationForm.is_valid():
            NewUserRegistrationForm.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/Login/")

        return render(request, 'my/reuse/register.html', {
            'NewUserRegistrationForm': NewUserRegistrationForm 
        })
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a super silly error of mine.

I switched my view definition to:

```
 def Registration(request):
    MyForm = NewUserRegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if MyForm.is_valid():
            MyForm.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/Login/")

    return render(request, 'VA/reuse/register.html', {
        'NewUserRegistrationForm': NewUserRegistrationForm 
    })
```

The `return render()` had to align with `if request.method` and I had to rename the form to something other than my forms declaration of `NewUserRegistrationForm`

Comment: did you imported it in the views, because i don't see those part in the views